# Delete all rows except the first - Java POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have read others questions similar to mine, but I miss something as none of my rows are deleted... After a lot of tries I have ended to the following code..

I want to delete all the rows except the 1st line, that's why the counter starts from 1...

```
//...
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\products.xls"));
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

for(int i=1; i<= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    deleteRow(sheet, row);
}

file.close();
FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\products.xls"));
workbook.write(outFile);
outFile.close();
//...


//The delete method...
private void deleteRow(HSSFSheet sheet, Row row) {
    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    int rowIndex = row.getRowNum();
    if(rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < lastRowNum){
        sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
    }
    if(rowIndex == lastRowNum){
        Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if(removingRow != null){
            sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
             System.out.println("Deleting.... ");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get any error, but none row is deleted.

**UPDATE**

As you mentioned below, I wasn't saving the file... I updated the code above where now I save it! However, some of my rows are deleted and not all of them...
Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yuor code works perfectly , only one thing missing : write the result to file ...

```
wb.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\products.xls")));
```

Complete working example:

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;


public class Main {

    public Main() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException {
        FileInputStream file = null;
        HSSFWorkbook wb = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
    try{
         file = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\products.xls"));

         wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        for(int i=1; i<= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
            deleteRow(sheet, row);
        }

         out = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\products.xls"));
        wb.write(out);


    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    finally{
        if(file!=null)
        file.close();
        if(out!=null)
        out.close();
        if(wb!=null)
        wb.close();
    }

    }
        public static void deleteRow(HSSFSheet sheet, Row row) {
            int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            int rowIndex = row.getRowNum();
            if(rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < lastRowNum){
                sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
            }
            if(rowIndex == lastRowNum){
                Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
                if(removingRow != null){
                    sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
                     System.out.println("Deleting.... ");
                }    
        }
    }

}
```

The only problem in your code its that the beavhiour its not what you expect from the method **deleteRow(..)** i modified your method in this way :

```
public static void deleteRow(HSSFSheet sheet, Row row) {
            int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();     
            if(lastRowNum !=0 && lastRowNum >0){
                int rowIndex = row.getRowNum();
                Row removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
                if(removingRow != null){
                    sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
                     System.out.println("Deleting.... ");
                }    
        }
    }
```

If there is only one row in the file , you will not delete , if there are more , you delete all the rows except the first one .

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Just update your answer the line where you write `wb.write...` with the `file.close();
FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\products.xls"));
workbook.write(outFile);
outFile.close();` to work properly.

Comment: Edit : i did it putting in a finally block to make it in a correct way

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to save your workbook apparently...

```
workbook.Save(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot save changes.